# How to encrypt a dnode connection?

Tags: node.js, ssl, dnode

I am using [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) as an RPC-style library within my Node.js application.

Now I would like to have secure dnode's connection using public-key-cryptography. I guess that this should be possible anyhow using Node.js' TLS module, but I have never used that, hence I am missing some experience with that.

Has anybody already done this, and can provide a small, but complete example on how to set up an encrypted and secured dnode connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it.

All you need to do is to create a TLS server / client and pipe its stream to dnode.

For an example see my question [How to verify that a connection is actually TLS secured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085444/how-to-verify-that-a-connection-is-actually-tls-secured)

Answer (score 2):

Substack has an example on the `upnode` page

https://github.com/substack/upnode/#ssl-stream-example

So for if you want to use `dnode`, just swap `upnode` out